# java String.valueOf issue

Tags: java, string, value-of

I wrote this code:

```
byte[] test = {-51};
byte[] test2 = {-51};
byte[] test3 = {-51};
System.out.println(String.valueOf(test));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(test2));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(test3));
```

And i've got a different results:

```
[B@9304b1
[B@190d11
[B@a90653
```

Why?

Comment: You're asking for the value of the array. What you probably want is String.valueOf(test[0])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) does not have a byte[] argument, so it will be processed as `Object` and the `toString()` method will be called, since arrays doesn't implements this method, [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) will be process in the array and it's result varies from each instance.

If you want to convert `byte[]` to String use the constructor [String(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) or [String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

```
byte[] test = {-51};
byte[] test2 = {-51};
byte[] test3 = {-51};
System.out.println(new String(test));
System.out.println(new String(test2));
System.out.println(new String(test3));
```

Result:

```
Í
Í
Í
```

If you want to view the content of the array use the [Arrays.toString(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29)

```
byte[] test = {-51};
byte[] test2 = {-51};
byte[] test3 = {-51};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test3));
```

Result:

```
[-51]
[-51]
[-51]
```

Answer (score 3):

The numbers you're seeing are the [hash codes of the array objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

To see the contents of the arrays, use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test3));
```

Answer (score 1):

the toString pf any array doesn't use the values in the array to create the string you can use [`Arrays.toString(test);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29) for that

Answer (score 0):

`ValueOf()` just calls `toString()` of given object. If you want to print the content of array use `Arrays.toString()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `String.valueOf` for a byte array, when you give it `byte[]`, it uses `String.valueOf(Object obj)`.